# I am getting the following error: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'

Tags: c++, string, vector, long-integer, bad-alloc

Ok so I have a string s that I repeat n times. For example I have "aba" and n = 10 and I want to find the
number of a's. So in this case (abaabaabaa) we have 7 a's. I wrote the following code that passes some of the test cases but when n is big I am getting the error:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc.
Is there a way to fix it? Thanks.

```
long repeatedString(string s, long n) {

    long i = 0, j = 0, cnt = 0;
    long sz = s.size();
    vector<char> ar;

    while (i < n)
    {
        ar.push_back(s[j]);
        j++;

        if (j >= sz)
        {
            j = 0;
        }

        i++;
    }

    i = 0;
    while (i < n)
    {
        if (ar[i] == 'a')
        {
            cnt++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return cnt;

}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Offtopic: You should reserve `ar` ahead of time. `ar.reserve(n)`

Comment: How big is `n` before it fails? If you repeat `s` many billions of times, you may simply not have enough memory to represent the resulting string.

Comment: @ François Andrieux If I do that I am not getting the right number of a's. Number of a's in "aba" is 2. But if I do 2*10, I get 20 when I should get 7 (abaabaabaa)

Comment: The only reason of std::bad_alloc is [Out of memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory). e.g.  System don't have enough free memory to allocate requested amount, or memory is to fragmented to allocate this block.

Comment: Are you sure that n < s.length()?  If not, all sorts of weird stuff will happen.

Comment: @ El Stepherino n is not less than s.length. For example s = "a" and n could be 1billion.

Comment: @VictorGubin I see. I misunderstood the meaning of `n`. You can still do this without generating the whole string. Either count the `'a'`s instead of generating `ar`. You can also count the `'a'`s in `s`, multiply that by `n / s.size()` and then only iterate over `s` for `n % s.size()` characters to see how many trailing `'a'`s need to be added to the count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the cause is that you are running out of memory. When you do `push_back`, the vector may be reallocating which would require `capacity + capacity * 2` (multiplier may vary) amount of space in a contiguous allocation. If you reserve ahead of time, this would fix that problem, but you would still need `n` contiguous bytes of memory.

A better solution is to just read the string and do some multiplication, like so:

```
size_t repeatedString( const std::string &s, size_t n ) {
    size_t sz = s.size();
    size_t cnt = 0;

    for ( const char &c : s ) {
        if ( c == 'a' ) {
            ++cnt;
        }
    }

    size_t mult = n / sz;
    cnt *= mult;
    size_t rem = n % sz;

    for ( size_t idx = 0; idx < rem; ++idx ) {
        if ( s[idx] == 'a' ) {
            ++cnt;
        }
    }

    return cnt;
}
```

This makes it so that you don't need to allocate an additional `n` bytes, so the memory is reduced.

Comment: That did it. Thank you!!